# How to replace a character "." of a specific cell with 0 in a Mac terminal?

Tags: awk, sed, terminal, grep

The txt file look like this:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cElTy.png)
I want this:
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpXVH.png)

Before:

```
2262493 565.7   1315.5  3617.0
2262494 488.3   1458.8  3445.0
2262495 366.0   1642.7  3269.0
2262496 .   .   0.0
```

After:

```
2262493 565.7   1315.5  3617.0
2262494 488.3   1458.8  3445.0
2262495 366.0   1642.7  3269.0
2262496 0   0   0.0
```

I need to replace the `.` in 2nd and 3rd column with `0`. I can't do it with this awk command:

```
awk '{gsub(".","0",$2); print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4}'
```

because there are a dot in every line.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat file
1.2 3.14 7.49 21.37
4.2  .    .    0.0

$ awk -v OFS="\t" '$2=="."{$2=0} $3=="."{$3=0} {$1=$1}1' file
1.2     3.14    7.49    21.37
4.2     0       0       0.0
```

If the second and/or third column is ".", set to "0". That last bit, `{$1=$1}1`, ensures that the separators are set to tab before printing the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat script.awk 
#{for(i=NF;i>0;i--)    # loop it backwards save a byte
{for(i=3;i>1;i--)     # oh it was only fields 2 and 3
    sub(/^\.$/,0,$i)  # sub lonely periods with zeros
} 1                   # one outputs zeros and more
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk jas\'s_file.txt
1.2 3.14 7.49 21.37
4.2 0 0 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

with `perl` by splitting input line on spaces and iterating over 2nd and 3rd column

```
$ cat file
. 3.14 7.49 21.37
4.2  .    .    0.0

$ perl -nale 'foreach (@F[1..2]){ $_ = "0" if $_ eq "." } print join"\t",@F' file
.   3.14    7.49    21.37
4.2 0   0   0.0
```

or, with regex

```
$ perl -nale 'foreach (@F[1..2]){ $_ = "0" if /^\.$/ } print join"\t",@F' file
.   3.14    7.49    21.37
4.2 0   0   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    cat file
2262493 565.7   1315.5  3617.0
2262494 488.3   1458.8  3445.0
2262495 366.0   1642.7  3269.0
2262496 .   .   0.0

awk 'sub(/^\.$/,"0",$2)sub(/^\.$/,"0",$3){print $1,$2"   "$3"\t"$4}' file
2262493 565.7   1315.5  3617.0
2262494 488.3   1458.8  3445.0
2262495 366.0   1642.7  3269.0
2262496 0   0   0.0
```